# cloud shell is not writing or displaying full set of records

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am running a simple script using `cloud shell` to get the selected records from a given table.

```
#!/bin/bash

bq query --format=pretty --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id='test-project' " \
  SELECT collecttime, count(distinct(CELLID)) countIngest \
FROM \`test-project.TEST_INGEST.my_test_table\` \
WHERE DATE(COLLECTTIME) >= '2020-12-01' \
group by collecttime order by collecttime;">>gsam_output.csv
```

If I run this query on `Google console` it fetched 500 records, a 100 each page and I can move from one page to another to see full set of records. I can also save results to some csv with full set of 500 records.

But when I run same query in `shell` or `cloud SDK` environment. It is only writing or displaying those records which gets displayed on first page in console. Is there any cap to write or display records via command line or shell?

Below I run in cloud SDK

```
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT collecttime, count(distinct(CELLID)) countIngest FROM TEST_INGEST.my_test_table WHERE DATE(COLLECTTIME) >= '2020-12-01' group by collecttime order by collecttime;">>gsam_output.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set `--max_rows` or `-n` option when using `bq query` command. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query) is the link to documentation describing this option.

I tried to run a similar query with this option set to 500, and it fetched 500 records at once.

```
 bq query -n 500 --format=pretty --use_legacy_sql=false "select * from bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright - so when you are looking at BQ output data, it can't paginate results for you. Which is what that is doing, which is why you only get the 1st page (I think)

What you want to try and do is *export* the data.

You write your data to a temp table in bq, and then export it - using directions here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq

or

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in_bigquery

You can also write a full output of a query to a csv using the console:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results

Also, try specifying your delimiter, and ensuring you don't have any nested information. CSV won't work for nested assets in bq, you need to jump to json.